Why does cmake throw LNK2019 even though the proper .lib file is linked?
I'm trying to create an API wrapper for Discord's GameSDK using Node's addon api and cmake-js. My code makes calls to Discord's libraries using their provided header files. However, I keep getting LNK2019 errors when trying to compile, even though the correct .lib file for my architecture is passed to the linker.
I'm using:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 with Visual C++ toolset (v170)

CMake >= 3.15

CMake-js 7.30


What I've Tried:

Ensuring all project source and header files are built

Setting my VCTargetsPath env variable to the proper directory

Reinstalling Visual Studio


Relevant files and outputs are below
cmake-js compile  output:
...
info CMD CLEAN
info RUN [
info RUN   'cmake',
info RUN   '-E',
info RUN   'remove_directory',
info RUN   'C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\Projects\\discord-gamesdk\\build'
info RUN ]
info CMD CONFIGURE
info find VS using VS2022 (17.10.35013.160) found at:
info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
info RUN [
info RUN   'cmake',
info RUN   'C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\Projects\\discord-gamesdk',
info RUN   '--no-warn-unused-cli',
info RUN   '-G',
info RUN   'Visual Studio 17 2022',
info RUN   '-A',
info RUN   'x64',
info RUN   '-DCMAKE_JS_VERSION=7.3.0',
info RUN   '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release',
info RUN   '-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\Projects\\discord-gamesdk\\build',
info RUN   '-DCMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY=MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>',
info RUN   '-DCMAKE_JS_INC=C:\\Users\\Nick\\.cmake-js\\node-x64\\v20.15.0\\include\\node',
info RUN   '-DCMAKE_JS_SRC=C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Projects/discord-gamesdk/node_modules/.pnpm/cmake-js@7.3.0/node_modules/cmake-js/lib/cpp/win_delay_load_hook.cc',
info RUN   '-DNODE_RUNTIME=node',
info RUN   '-DNODE_RUNTIMEVERSION=20.15.0',
info RUN   '-DNODE_ARCH=x64',
info RUN   '-DCMAKE_JS_LIB=C:\\Users\\Nick\\.cmake-js\\node-x64\\v20.15.0\\win-x64\\node.lib',
info RUN   '-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=/DELAYLOAD:NODE.EXE'
info RUN ]
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33811.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33811.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Linked libraries: C:\Users\Nick\.cmake-js\node-x64\v20.15.0\win-x64\node.libC:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Projects/discord-gamesdk/lib/discord_game_sdk.dll.lib
-- Configuring done (5.2s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Projects/discord-gamesdk/build
info CMD BUILD
info RUN [
info RUN   'cmake',
info RUN   '--build',
info RUN   'C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\Projects\\discord-gamesdk\\build',
info RUN   '--config',
info RUN   'Release'
info RUN ]
MSBuild version 17.10.4+10fbfbf2e for .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Projects/discord-gamesdk/CMakeLists.txt
  activity.cpp
  core.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  Generating Code...
     Creating library C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Projects/discord-gamesdk/build/Release/discord_gamesdk.lib and object C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Projects/discord-gamesdk/build/Release/discord_gamesdk.exp
activity.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl discord::ActivityManager::UpdateActivity(class discord::Activity const &,class std::function<void __cdecl(enum discord::Res
ult)>)" (?UpdateActivity@ActivityManager@discord@@QEAAXAEBVActivity@2@V?$function@$$A6AXW4Result@discord@@@Z@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl Activity::updateActivityWrapped(class Napi::Cal
lbackInfo const &)" (?updateActivityWrapped@Activity@@YAXAEBVCallbackInfo@Napi@@@Z) [C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Projects\discord-gamesdk\build\discord_gamesdk.vcxproj]
activity.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class discord::ActivityManager & __cdecl discord::Core::ActivityManager(void)" (?ActivityManager@Core@discord@@QEAAAEAV02@XZ) referenced
 in function "void __cdecl Activity::updateActivityWrapped(class Napi::CallbackInfo const &)" (?updateActivityWrapped@Activity@@YAXAEBVCallbackInfo@Napi@@@Z) [C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Projects\discord-game
sdk\build\discord_gamesdk.vcxproj]
activity.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class discord::Activity __cdecl Activity::parseActivityFromObject(class Napi::Object)" (?parseActivityFromObject@Activity@@YA?AV1discord@@VObjec
t@Napi@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl Activity::updateActivityWrapped(class Napi::CallbackInfo const &)" (?updateActivityWrapped@Activity@@YAXAEBVCallbackInfo@Napi@@@Z) [C:\Users\Nick\Desktop
\Projects\discord-gamesdk\build\discord_gamesdk.vcxproj]
core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static enum discord::Result __cdecl discord::Core::Create(__int64,unsigned __int64,class discord::Core * *)" (?Create@Core@discord@@SA?AW4Re
sult@2@_J_KPEAPEAV12@@Z) referenced in function "class Napi::Number __cdecl Discord::createWrapped(class Napi::CallbackInfo const &)" (?createWrapped@Discord@@YA?AVNumber@Napi@@AEBVCallbackInfo@3@@Z) [C
:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Projects\discord-gamesdk\build\discord_gamesdk.vcxproj]
core.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: enum discord::Result __cdecl discord::Core::RunCallbacks(void)" (?RunCallbacks@Core@discord@@QEAA?AW4Result@2@XZ) referenced in function "vo
id __cdecl Discord::runCallbacksWrapped(class Napi::CallbackInfo const &)" (?runCallbacksWrapped@Discord@@YAXAEBVCallbackInfo@Napi@@@Z) [C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Projects\discord-gamesdk\build\discord_game
sdk.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Projects\discord-gamesdk\build\Release\discord_gamesdk.node : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals [C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Projects\discord-gamesdk\build\discord_gamesdk.vcxp
roj]
ERR! OMG Process terminated: 1
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project (discord_gamesdk)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include_directories(${CMAKE_JS_INC} include "./")

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "src/backend/*.cpp" "src/backend/*.h")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${CMAKE_JS_SRC})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "" SUFFIX ".node")

find_library(DISCORD_GAME_SDK 
NAMES discord_game_sdk discord_game_sdk.dll
HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
PATH_SUFFIXES lib
REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_JS_LIB})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DISCORD_GAME_SDK})

get_target_property(OUT ${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_LIBRARIES)
message(STATUS "Linked libraries: " ${OUT})

# Output:
# -- Linked libraries: C:\Users\Nick\.cmake-js\node-x64\v20.15.0\win-x64\node.libC:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Projects/discord-gamesdk/lib/discord_game_sdk.dll.lib

# Include N-API wrappers
execute_process(COMMAND node -p "require('node-addon-api').include"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE NODE_ADDON_API_DIR
        )
string(REPLACE "\n" "" NODE_ADDON_API_DIR ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR})
string(REPLACE "\"" "" NODE_ADDON_API_DIR ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${NODE_ADDON_API_DIR})
add_definitions(-DNAPI_VERSION=3)

core.h:
#include <napi.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef DISCORD
#define DISCORD
#include "include/discord.h"
#endif

using namespace std;

extern discord::Core *core;

namespace Discord
{
    void runCallbacksWrapped(Napi::CallbackInfo const &);
    Napi::Number createWrapped(Napi::CallbackInfo const &);
    Napi::Number getVersionWrapped(Napi::CallbackInfo const &);
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports);

core.cpp:
#include "core.h"

extern discord::Core *core{};

void Discord::runCallbacksWrapped(Napi::CallbackInfo const &info)
{
    ::core->RunCallbacks();
}

/**
 * @param info clientId: Number, createFlags: Number
 */
Napi::Number Discord::createWrapped(Napi::CallbackInfo const &info)
{
    auto env = info.Env();
    if (info.Length() < 2)
    {
        throw ERROR_BAD_ARGUMENTS;
    }
    assert(info[0].IsNumber());
    assert(info[1].IsNumber());

    auto clientId = (discord::ClientId)info[0].As<Napi::Number>().Int64Value();
    auto createFlags = info[1].As<Napi::Number>().Int64Value();
    return Napi::Number::New(env,
                             (double)discord::Core::Create(
                                 clientId,
                                 createFlags,
                                 &core));
}

Napi::Number Discord::getVersionWrapped(Napi::CallbackInfo const &info)
{
    return Napi::Number::New(info.Env(), DISCORD_VERSION);
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports)
{
    exports.Set("getVersion", Napi::Function::New(env, Discord::getVersionWrapped));
    exports.Set("create", Napi::Function::New(env, Discord::createWrapped));
    exports.Set("runCallbacks", Napi::Function::New(env, Discord::runCallbacksWrapped));
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(discordgamesdk, Init)


The sdk library only has the c interface, you need to compile the c++ code yourself

The errors reported make me suspect that include/discord.h was not included in core.h.  In core.h, include/discord.h is included, but with an include guard.  In MSVS, pragma once can be used as an include guard.  discord.h contains pragma once on the first line.  In the include guard, you might try to make DISCORD more unique, or remove the guard from core.h altogether.
